# Building a “if” statement circuit where i can control different light diodes

Tags: audio, microphone, low-noise-amplifier

I want to design a circuit to react in different ways depending if a microphone picks up one frequency and in different way if it picks up the some other frequency.

I want different lights to shine depending on what signal is coming from the microphone.

The circuit will only be analog.

The frequencies will be fairly far apart from each other, one of the sounds has around 0,5 seconds of pause time between beeps and the other has a couple seconds.

Comment: You asked this exact question earlier - why did you abandon that question and delete it? Didn't you receive plenty of useful comments? I remember seeing some.

Comment: I am new to the forum and my last post got closed because of lack of information, so now i have re-done it with some more information

Comment: Please reinstate your earlier question. Nobody is going like repeating what they said as comments in this question; they will see you deleting your older question as possibly rude so, please reinstate your previous question. As far as I remember, what you wrote before is no different to what you have written here. Plus somebody provided a useful link for you and now that link is lost without reinstating the earlier question.

Comment: It still lacks information. Define all input levels, frequencies and sequences and specs for all outputs.  Otherwise , it looks like a "Color organ design"

Comment: Also, I suggest that **you** find some usable circuits (start with Tony's suggestion) and do the pre-work of selecting some circuits that might be useful. We don't do "I want this and that, give me a circuit" type of questions.

Comment: Ah ... the color organ circuit. In high school it was my second project, after the light dimmer circuit. I printed some PCBs and put them into walnut cabinets with clear diffuser plastic fronts. I sold a few.